# Компиляция scss через node-sass в разные директории

Tags: css, npm, scss, node-modules

Имеется директория `src/styles/` в которой лежат папки, в каждой из которых файл `.scss` (т.е. получается что то вроде `src/styles/*/*.scss)`.

Нужно скомпилировать `.scss` с помощью `node-sass` не в одну папку, а туда где лежит компилируемый файл (т.е. `src/styles/{дирретория_исходника}/*.css`).

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, с помощью gulp можно сделать так.

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {
    gulp.src('src/styles/*/*.sсss')
        .pipe(scss().on('error', scss.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/styles/'));
});
```